# Custom payment Gateway ( Magento 2.3 )

Tags: magento2

How can I develop a custom payment gateway in magento 2.3 version.
I tried many tutorials but none of them is working correctly. 
What tutorial best to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created your module like `app/code/Vendor/Module` then follow these steps

in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="1000" translate="label">
            <group id="custompayment" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
                <label>custompayment</label>
                <field id="active" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label" type="select">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="title" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="20" translate="label" type="text">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="order_status" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="30" translate="label" type="select">
                    <label>New Order Status</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\NewStatus</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="allowspecific" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="40" translate="label" type="allowspecific">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="50" translate="label" type="multiselect">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="60" translate="label" type="text">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                </field>
                <field id="instructions" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="70" translate="label" type="textarea">
                    <label>Instructions</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <custompayment>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>Vendor\Module\Model\Payment\Custompayment</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>custompayment</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </custompayment>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/payment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
    <methods>
        <method name="custompayment">
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
        </method>
    </methods>
</payment>
```

in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Payment/Custompayment.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Payment;

class Custompayment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{

    protected $_code = "custompayment";
    protected $_isOffline = true;

    public function isAvailable(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    ) {
        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }
}
```

in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custompayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/payment/custompayment</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="custompayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/custompayment-method.js`

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Module/payment/custompayment'
            },
            getMailingAddress: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
            getInstructions: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
            },
        });
    }
);
```

in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/custompayment.js`

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'custompayment',
                component: 'Vendor_Module/js/view/payment/method-renderer/custompayment-method'
            }
        );
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/custompayment.html`

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will create new payment with name `custompayment` :)

Comment: do I need to develop using this folder structure?
   " app/code/Vendor/Module "
and place this payment gateway to this directory
   " magento2\vendor ".

Comment: No, Replace all Vendors with company name and all Modules with your module name

Comment: To make it more easy for you, you can use module generator. Try this website: https://mage2gen.com/

Comment: It also have payment method option, from which you can create your own payment method

Comment: Thank you saved my life :)

Comment: Good to hear that :) Please vote on answer and mark it correct so that in future it would helpful to others too

Comment: How to install this gateway to magento. Where to place this package file / what are the next steps to follow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100403/discussion-between-garry-and-shoaib-munir).

Comment: Please mark answer correct if you issue resolved

Comment: All working fine except Place Order Button is not appearing on Magento 2.3.5-p1 @Shoaib Munir can you help?

Comment: Is it possible to use this payment method also in the backend ("create order" function)? I have created my method and I can also use it in the backend, but I cannot see the details (custompayment-method.js).

Answer (score 0):

it's  work  but it's not good  way  , you  must not use AbstractMethod  its  deprecated.

see  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/base-integration/integration-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

To develop a custom payment gateway in Magento 2.3 version

Visit here - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/base-integration/integration-intro.html